# What do you call the multi-window slider effect in Windows 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What would you call the slider effect when you press Windows + Tab key in Windows 7, and it displays layers of windows which can be scrolled through?

[image: layers of windows]

What do you call this 3D transition in terms of jQuery? (Like fade in, fade out) Any reference would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft calls their effect [Aero Flip 3D](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-multiple-windows%231TC=windows-7&section_2).

I couldn't find a specific jQuery plugin to do the Aero Flip 3D effect exactly. I did find many examples of 3D flip effects. Checkout the [3D plugins](http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/3D/) on [jQueryscript.net](http://www.jqueryscript.net/).